# How to make breadcrumb URL SEO friendly

Tags: breadcrumbs

so I have breadcrumbs in breadcrumbs.phtml and I don't know how to change their format for example I have this in $crumbs:

```
  [category1484] => Array
        (
            [label] => Laptop
            [link] => http://www.someweb.com/radioshack/catalog/category/view/s/laptop/id/1484/
            [title] => 
            [first] => 
            [last] => 
            [readonly] => 
        )
```

Instead I want to have the url keys for the breadcrumb so that I have like this:

```
http://www.someweb.com/radioshack/laptop
```

for example in products I could use to get urls like this:

```
 <a href="<?php  echo  Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()."/".$prod->geturl_key(); ?>">
```

But I do not have this option in bread crumbs should I customize breadcrumbs and start over or can I change the format?

We have url rewrites in just one store and we can show the products and categories by url_key but for breadcrumbs I have problem and if you ask why you have just for one store it is because we needed it to be faster so we kept it in just one store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by changing Rewrite.php  it was in a core file so I copy pastes in local file and then changed as following:

path: `/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php`

I changed this getstoreid to the store that I have url rewrite for which is 1:

```
 $select->where('store_id IN(?)', array(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID, $object->getStoreId()));
```

to

`$select->where('store_id IN(?)', array(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID, 1))`;

Answer (score 1):

Replace your breadcrumbs.phtml with this:

```
<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<ul>
    <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>">
        <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
        <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
            <span>/ </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Ensure that:

```
System > Configuration > General > Web > Search Engine Optimizations > Use Web Server Rewrites = 'Yes'

System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Web > Search Engine Optimizations > Product URL Suffix is empty 

System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Web > Search Engine Optimizations > Use Categories Path for Product URLs = 'Yes'
```

Reindex Catalog URL Rewrites

Flush Cache

Reload Page

Comment: I checked all configuration options that you told me and all were the same and I changed it to your code and still I have the same unfriendly urls

Comment: BACKUP DB and then truncate core_url_rewrite table, flush cache and reload

Comment: ok let me see what will happen

Comment: I do not have any in my table now and it doesn't show the page

Comment: Sorry System > Index Management > Catalog UrL Rewrites > reindex data

Comment: yes now I reindexed them and still I have the same rewrite urls :D no change!

Comment: You may need to add a slash for the product url suffix to be valid

Comment: Also please verify you have set a valid URL key for the product

Comment: we have url rewrites for just one of the stores for our speed and that's why it is happening